# Sass @mixin breakpoints only processing mobile/tablet styles

Tags: html, sass, media-queries, mixins

In an effort to better understand the use of Sass mixins I am trying to learn to use them for my media query breakpoints and it only seems to be processing them above and below `37.5em`. So, if you look at the SCSS code I have posted below, it will render the styles for `mobileonly`(*below* `37.5em` on the viewport window) and `phablet`(*above* `37.5em` on the viewport window), but not for `laptop` or `desktop`. When the viewport window is stretched larger it will not change past my `$firefly` hexidecimal variable I declared. According to Chrome dev tools, the media queries appear to be working, but the `@media (min-width: 37.5em)` seems to be overwriting the styles still because the styles that I want are crossed out in dev tools. So, even at the full viewport window size,`@media (min-width: 37.5em)` is the only style being applied. Why would this be?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/fr8du7a1/) is a jsfiddle of my exact issue.

And, for further clarification, here's my code:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/build/main.css">
  </head>
<body>
  <header>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

SCSS:

```
$azure: #f3f4f4;
$chateau-green: #2bb656;
$firefly: #364141;
$fern: #59cb59;
$pastel-green: #75dd66;
$pigment-green: #0ca750;

@mixin breakpoint($point) {
  @if $point == desktop {
    @media (min-width: 70em) { @content ; }
 }
  @else if $point == laptop {
    @media (min-width: 64em) { @content ; }
 }
   @else if $point == tablet {
    @media (min-width: 50em) { @content ; }
 }
  @else if $point == phablet {
    @media (min-width: 37.5em)  { @content ; }
 }
 @else if $point == mobileonly {
    @media (max-width: 37.5em)  { @content ; }

 }
}

header {
  height: 600px;
  width:100%;
  @include breakpoint(desktop) {
    background-color:$azure;
  }
  @include breakpoint(laptop) {
    background-color:$chateau-green;
  }
  @include breakpoint(phablet) {
    background-color:$firefly;
  }
  @include breakpoint(mobileonly) {
        background-color:$pastel-green;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added Outputed CSS:

```
header {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 70em) {
  header {
    background-color: #f3f4f4;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 64em) {
  header {
    background-color: #2bb656;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 37.5em) {
  header {
    background-color: #364141;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 37.5em) {
  header {
    background-color: #75dd66;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the style written for `min-width: 37.5em` overwrites the style written for `min-width: 64em` and similarly for other cases as well. For this, try to set the `min-width` as well as `max-width` both, so that the style is specific.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/8LLs84ar/1/) is the js fiddle.

Comment: This definitely worked. Thanks a lot. For some reason I figured `min-width` would override when a new width was reached in the viewport window.